# Show that if $A^{k+1}=0$ for some nonnegative integer $k$ then $A$ is singular...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^{k+1}=0$ for some nonnegative integer $k$, then
$A$ is singular, but $I−A$ is nonsingular and
$(I − A)^{−1} = I + A + A^2 + \cdots + A^k$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^{k+1} = 0$ then $$0 = \det A^{k+1} = (\det A)^{k+1}$$ giving $\det A = 0$ and $A$ is therefore singular.

For the second part calculate

$$(I-A)\sum_{n=0}^k A^n = I - A^{k+1} = I$$